# Getting someones IP Address through server

Tags: server, ip

How can I get a list of the connected IPs of a gaming server? I am trying to code a patch that can mask the IPs, but how can I even find them in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean by connected IP.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context here. You run the server and you want to know how someone *else* could determine other IPs? Does it matter that it's a gaming server? What's the connection architecture? Hub/spoke? P2P? What role does the server play between the clients? It seems to me that you are the only one who can answer how someone would find another's IP on the server ...

Comment: How you are you planning on hiding them?  The server has to know where to send back information about the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely dependent on implementation details.

If the server communicated with clients over TCP, then the server could keep a list of all clients that currently have open TCP connections.

If the server communicates over UDP, then the server would need to keep a list of IPs that have communicated with it recently.